# Laravel 5.3 - Structuring controllers into Modules with separate sessions, authorisation requirements and standard functionality/services

Tags: php, laravel-5, architecture

We have built and continue to develop a web application in php, based on an in-house web-framework. Our web-framework was written before Ruby on rails was anywhere and certainly before anything similar was available in php (ie before Symfony). We have often reviewed using a more standard framework, but until recently there was too much functionality missing for what we were doing (particularly queues, jobs etc).

We believe that now frameworks like laravel 5+ cover what our framework does and more. It's more modern, more expressive, etc, so we are considering rewriting our application using laravel 5, because it will be easier to obtain programming resources etc. We have been researching laravel, but have little experience with it.

This question is about how to approach the general architecture using laravel Controllers, Providers and Middleware, Auth, Routing etc. Our application has about 250 Controllers and our model has about 110 SQL tables using Propel ORM (which we would obviously migrate to Eloquent). The 250 Controllers are structured into what we call "modules", each of which is targeted at a different subset of the userbase. Our application serves "organisations" who have "members" some of whom are "administrators" for an organisation.  This is an outline of the "module" structure:

**Modules**

**pub**     : Publicly viewable pages, no login or session, trivial really

**org**     : Publicly viewable pages for each organisation every (!) page has the context of an organisation and all the routes have a "slug" for the org in them

**sec**     : extends "org" module, but now the member has logged in, so every page/route has context of *member AND org*. Facilitates transactions between the member and the organisation.

**orgadm**  : extends "org" module, but an organisation administrator is logged in. they can access slightly modified versions of the "org" pages and completely separate "orgadm" routes/pages for administering all the data of the organisation.

**mem**     : there is NO org context here (ie no org slug), but a member has logged in and can see all of the organisations to which they belong, manage their own personal data, etc...

**adm**     : Superadmins (internal staff) who can view/manage all orgs and all members

**sysadm**  : Only for sysadmins who are monitoring jobs/queues etc...

**restapi** : self explanatory

**Sessions**

pub                   : requires no login or session

org, sec, orgadm, mem : share a session / cookie.

> EDIT: In response to one of the comments a clarification of what we mean by "shared session". Some examples
>
> 1. Almost any e-commerce site, has a session on the public pages for
>      cart/basket. Once the user logs in the same cart contents continue
>      to be in session, but the user_id (or similar) is now also present.
>      So now the user also has access to their account / payment details
>      and can enter into a transaction with the merchant. This, in a
>      simplified way, is similar to what is happening in our org & sec
>      modules respectively.
> 2. On any wordpress site, if the user is logged and has administrative
>      privileges then the public UI is modified to include "admin"
>      nav in bar at top of pages (or similar) and following that nav,
>      leads to an entirely separate "administrative interface". This, in a
>      simplified way,  is similar to how our org and orgadm modules work.
>
> The sessions between org/sec/orgadm (also also mem) are thus "shared".
>   We would appreciate any feedback, but are reasonably confident it
>   makes sense.

adm and sysadm        : share a **different** session / cookie. The cookie has "path" set, all routes have that prefix, and the user db is completely separate (and quite small).

**Common "services" and functionality**

org,sec,orgadm : extend the same base and offer certain services to all of the controllers in those modules.

**Initial ideas for Laravel architecture & specific questions**

With our, currently reasonably naive, understanding of laravel 5.3, the simplest ideas to address each of the above seems to be:

- Write some abstract Controller classes which represent the "modules".
  Concrete Controlers for each "module" extend the appropriate abstract
  class. The abstract class provides the common functionality for the
  module either by containing the methods itself or by acting as a
  conduit to some laravel "Provider" which we write for each of our
  "modules". Is this is sane in laravel terms? We think it might work
  for org,sec,mem,orgadm (the core of the app)?
- To differentiate between our org, sec and orgadm modules, we have
  our own concept of "roles in an organisation". We
  are not sure this fits well with laravel authorisation, but maybe
  that's not insurmountable?
- For adm and sysadm we have no idea how to implement the "seperate
  session/cookie" aspect. We think this is important from a security
  perspective. Our only thought in a laravel world is to use subdomains
  and almost separate apps accessing the same backend DB instead?
- restapi: similar to adm etc...really should this be done as an entirely separate app as well? Currently it provides mainly an API to the orgadm data, but will be extended to include org module data (ie the publicly visible org stuff), so organisations can implement their own frontends.

This stackoverflow question:

[What is the correct way to break a larger Laravel 5 project into modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048473/what-is-the-correct-way-to-break-a-larger-laravel-5-project-into-modules)

seems to make some partial suggestions for some of the above aspects (ie division into modules from a routing and controller direcetory sytructure perpective), but nothing about the auth/session stuff.

This blogpost:

http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2015/12/03/creating-a-modular-application-in-laravel/

addresses some similar issues, and goes a little further in terms of namespaces, loading the controllers/models/views for the active module using a ServiceProvider. However it still does not address auth/session aspects.

Sorry for all the detail, hope the questions are clear.

Comment: Regarding your modules, take a look at the laravel Middlewares, which can help you filter out HTTP requests based on anything you decide (session/cookie/persmission) https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Comment: Sharing sessions? Sounds bad for me. In modules avoid globals.

Comment: @schellingerht not quite sure what you mean by "modules" in your comment. In our app, the central 4 "modules" (using our vocab) (org, sec, orgadm, mem) need to share a session. They are a fluid experience for the user, just different views on the data depending on the context (ie whether relative to a specific organisation, and whether logged in and as "who", ie what role for that organisaton). Is that what you mean we should avoid? Or does it depend on the definition of what we / you mean by the term "module"?

Comment: You're right: the term 'module' is abstract. Simply, I mean loose coupled (internal) packages to make your app maintainable, scalable, testable, etc. In that case, that packages should not depend on globals, such as sessions.

Comment: Different forms of authentication can be handled with middlewares, and increased granularity can be obtained by controller namespacing and/or route prefixing.